# Scoping an elasticsearch aggregation with a query and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to scope an aggregation based on the query and filter. I'm able to do the following things:

1. Scope the aggregation as global, but then I can only specify filters to further shrink the aggregation result set. I'm unable to specify a query (or multi_match).
2. Inherit the scope of the overall elasticsearch query (so multi_match), but I'm unable to remove a filter that was specified in the overall request.

Here is an example of 1:

```
{
  'colors' => {
    global: {},
    aggs: {
      results: {
        filter: {
          bool: {
            must: my_filters_without_this_filter(filter_to_ignore),
          },
        },
        aggs: {
          results: {
            terms: {
              field: 'color',
              size: 10,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

The issue is I'm unable to specify a search string towards the aggregation with the above.

And my other option is to simply inherit the overall query, but then I can't remove a filter:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "colors": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [, {
                        "terms": {
                            "colors": ["red", "white", "blue", "green"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "results": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "colors",
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "function_score": {
                    "boost_mode": "replace",
                    "functions": [{
                        "script_score": {
                            "script": "my_script"
                        }
                    }],
                    "query": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "fields": ["name^6", "description", "barcode^2"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "zero_terms_query": "all"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "colors": ["red"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above query i'd like to ignore the filter specified (color red) for the purpose of the aggregation.

Is it possible to have a globally scoped aggregation but also specify a filter AND a query?

I'd prefer to not make 2 elasticsearch queries per request, but it looks like I may need to.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a post_filter so the aggregations are built before the final filter.